# Drones in Barbados - importation banned, but personal use?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, drones, barbados

I am visiting Barbados and was hoping to take a DJI drone for photography. I read some articles about the country banning the importation of drones into the country. As I will not be selling my drone, I believed I'd be allowed to bring it, but [this article](http://www.abovebarbados.com/blog/press-release-defence-security-drone-ban) states the ban also applies to visitors of the island.

[This source](http://wiki.drones.fsd.ch/doku.php?id=barbados) states that there are four designated areas on the island where you are allowed to fly drones. How can I verify these sources? If it is true, will I have any other Barbados-specific trouble at the airport, assuming I will only fly in designated areas?

[An article from Barbados Today](https://www.barbadostoday.bb/2015/05/24/drone-operators-beware/) was helpful but not able to answer my question. It looks like I will also require a special license to operate the drone.

Comment: The article seems pretty clear that you can't bring it in at all.  "Importation" in this context seems to refer to bringing it into the country for any reason, regardless of whether you plan to sell it.  That seems to make the question about designated flying areas moot.

Comment: hmm thank you, I didn't realize that. the first article I linked states "for a period of six months ending September 30, 2016 in the first instance and until further notice". but other sources are saying 12 months as of march 2016. Having trouble finding an official statement. @NateEldredge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a visitor, whenever you bring personal items in, you are legally "importing" them.  They don't charge you duty because you will also be "exporting" them when you depart.  So any restrictions on importing certain items applies equally to commercial enterprises and tourists.